# RadGrid- How to disable horizontal drag and drop feature

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, radgrid

I need to disable horizontal drag and drop feature in RadGrid but i need to this facility on the vertical  how to do it.
There should be restricted same column only not allowed next column
 i have using asp.net with C#

Answer (score 1):

Yes....I got the Answer :)

Put it on the OnRowDrop event

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.HtmlElement)) 
       {
           if (e.DraggedItems[0].OwnerGridID == e.DestDataItem.OwnerGridID)   
            {
               -------                   
            }
         }
```